# Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'ip' cannot be null (SQL: insert into `users` (`name`, `steamid`, `avatar`, `token`, `ip`)

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, web, phpmyadmin

So i am trying to login to my site via steam api and this error pops up SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'ip' cannot be null. SQL:

```
insert into `users` (`name`, `steamid`, `avatar`, `token`, `ip`)
```

i use laravel php7.0 and phpmyadmin on a ubuntu 16.04 server vmware

[This is the structure of my database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gtQSB.png)

[And this is the users one where i have problems](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0f73L.png)

If you could help me out it would be amazing thanks

code:

```
CREATE TABLE `users` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `ip` text NOT NULL,
  `steamid` varchar(17) NOT NULL,
  `wagered` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `wags` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `wwags` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `deps` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `depamount` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `withs` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `withamount` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `can_withdraw` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `available` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `aff` varchar(17) NOT NULL,
  `affs` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `affamount` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `affcollected` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(256) NOT NULL,
  `balance` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `rank` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `steam_level` int(11) DEFAULT '-1',
  `mute` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `ban` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `avatar` text NOT NULL,
  `dailygift` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `hourlygift` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `redeemed_code` text NOT NULL,
  `disabled_send` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `disabled_withdraw` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `token` varchar(128) NOT NULL,
  `last` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Comment:  Please post code, errors, sample data or textual output here as plain-text, not as images that can be hard to read, can’t be copy-pasted to help test code or use in answers, and are barrier to those who depend on screen readers or translation tools. You can edit your question to add the code in the body of your question. For easy formatting use the `{}` button to mark blocks of code, or indent with four spaces for the same effect. The contents of a **screenshot can’t be searched, run as code, or copied and edited to create a solution.**

Comment: Problem is pretty clear: `ip` column cannot be NULL. Either populate it, or change your schema so it can be NULL.

Comment: Instead of these near useless screenshots, please include the result of `SHOW CREATE TABLE` instead. This is *much* easier to read, and as a plus, can be used to build and test solutions. The screenshots you have here are not only huge and full of junk we can't click on which just takes up space, but don't even include the key information: Can that column be NULL or not and does it have a `DEFAULT`. The `SHOW CREATE TABLE` version shows all of this very concisely.

Comment: here is the code https://pastebin.com/s2GKRqJt

Comment: Please edit your question to include it, not as an external link. Sorry to be so particular, but a lot of us review a *bunch* of questions and popping open extra windows to see your code is not productive.

Comment: done ive included the code

Comment: I've trimmed it down to just the `users` table.

Comment: thanks sorry i forgot to trim it myself

Comment: Check your database. Null column should be 'Yes' for ip

Comment: the ip it is null

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The definition for this column is:

```sql
`ip` text NOT NULL,
```

Which is both egregiously huge, as `TEXT` is intended to support up to 64K of data, and also strictly "NOT NULL" which means it *must* be populated.

You probably want to alter it to be:

```sql
ip VARCHAR(255) NULL,
```

Which you can do with a Laravel migration.

Comment: i've changed it ALTER TABLE `users` CHANGE `ip` `ip` VARCHAR(255) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci NOT NULL; and it says the same thing when i try to log in

Comment: The key here is `NOT NULL` means, specifically, explicitly, "reject NULL values" but you want accept them, so remove the `NOT`.

Comment: wait now it says something else SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'ip' cannot be null (SQL: insert into `logins` (`ip`, `steamid`, `time`)

Answer (score 0):

You must gives us more information and revelant code parts, you should avoid external links.

Nevertheless, with the informations in your post you do not have the value part in your request.

```sql
INSERT INTO `users` (`name`, `steamid`, `avatar`, `token`, `ip`)  VALUES ($name, $steamid, $avatar, $token, $ip);
```

because as mentionned in your SQL file you force your values to be non-null.

Comment: i inserted the code you provided and the same thing happened returned the same error

Comment: You have to adapt the variables in the value part